# Getting error for libxml2.2.dylib "file is not of required architecture"

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-1.9, rvm

I'm trying to use rvm to install Ruby 1.9.2 on my Mac running Snow Leopard.

My `.bash_profile` contains

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

To install ruby, I run:

```
rvm install 1.9.2 -C --enable-shared
```

I get an error during compiling. Here is the make.error.log:

```
[2010-01-20 10:03:00] make 
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libxml2.2.dylib, file is not of required architecture
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../.ext/i386-darwin10.2.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

**EDIT:**

I installed readline from source and tried the install like this:

```
rvm install 1.9.2 -C --enable-shared,--with-readline-dir=/usr/local
```

which resulted in the same error as before.

The locations of the rcltklib.bundle file is:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9.7.0/tcltklib.bundle
```

(I think this file is part of the Ruby OSX installation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now, finally I figured it out.
I did install ruby 1.8.7 from **rubyosx** and there seemed to be some broken libraries, which rvm used to compile its rubies.

The solution is to remove the rubyosx ruby from `/usr/local`.

The less drastic solution is to just rename the `/usr/local` folder during compiling with rvm. Afterwards you can name it back and it works as expected.

Glad it works now.

Comment: Had this same problem without the changes you made to the .bash_profile...thanks for the post!

Comment: Thanks for this post. Moving /usr/local out of the way worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting ARCHFLAGS to two different architectures. Why? Try with only `-arch -x86_64` (which as far as I know, is the default in snow leopard).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Copied this line somewhere, but the i386 seems in fact unnecessary.  
Didn't solve the problem though.

Comment: OK. For me it "just works" on snow leopard. Next thing to make sure is that you have all the latest and greatest xCode http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/