# RVM Does Not Install Ruby 1.9.2 on Snow Leopard: 'Error running 'make '

Tags: ruby, rvm

When I try to install Ruby 1.9.2 on Snow Leopard using:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

I get the following:

```
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /Users/mary/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/make.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

So, I check out make.log. The end of it reads:

```
readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
readline.c:1386: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this 
function)

readline.c:1386: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:1386: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

I have consulted other answers to this question, and done everything suggested there:

- XCode is installed.
- The end of my .bash_profile has the following line added to it:

  ```
  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
  ```

I have tried updating readline, but no matter what, I continue to get the error message about running 'make.'

The output of rvm info is the following:

```
 system:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin mary-nunans-computer.local 10.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.6.0: Wed Nov 10 18:13:17 PST 2010; root:xnu-1504.9.26~3/RELEASE_I386 i386"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.6.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  homes:
    gem:          "not set"
    ruby:         "not set"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/mary/.rvm/bin:/Users/mary/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     ""
    GEM_PATH:     ""
    MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
    IRBRC:        ""
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: For some reason, people don't think to check the RVM site for help on this issue: http://beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/

Comment: Thanks "the Tin Man" -- you are correct, that section under "readline" was exactly what helped me. I'm finally 1.9.2 after hours of trying to install on a fresh version of Mac OSX Mountain Lion and 1.9.2.

Comment: @theTinMan I cannot access that link. Is it the same as this one? https://rvm.io/packages/readline/

Answer (score 18):

Compile and install your own readline:

```
curl -O ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-6.1.tar.gz
tar xzvf readline-6.1.tar.gz
cd readline-6.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

Remove the ruby: `rvm remove 1.9.2`

Install it again: `rvm install 1.9.2`

(You might need to add source it if local path is not in your directory: `rvm install 1.9.1 -C --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/`

That should do it.

------------- EDIT --------------

As noted in the comment below, if you use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), then you should `brew install readline`.  And if you're using a Mac, you *should* be using homebrew.

------------ HOW TO COMPILE READLINE ON 10.7 ---------

"readline-6.2 has not been updated for Mac OS X 10.7 (darwin11), so open the support/shobj-conf and change darwin10 to darwin11 in the two places where it appears."

Source: [lamboy](https://web.archive.org/web/20200811170646/https://blog.csdn.net/lamboy/article/details/7248102)

Comment: I've been fighting this for a few hours now and this finally solved the issue for me. Thanks!!

Comment: If you use homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew, recommended!), compiling and installing readline is done with `brew install readline`. Install ruby with `rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.1/`.

Comment: I ran into yet another level errors compiling readline that were fixed by http://www.iamseree.com/application-development/readline-6-2-make-error-in-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: This helped me on FreeBSD 9 as well.  I installed ruby though 2.0.0.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the answer in the post [Getting error for libxml2.2.dylib "file is not of required architecture"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100187/error-installing-ruby-1-9-with-rvm-under-snow-leopard)) finally helped me resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install developer tools.  You can download Xcode (the developer tools comes with it) for 5 dollars at the mac app store.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pasting the output of 'rvm notes' here as this matters directly. You need at least Xcode 3.2.1 (1613). Please note that Snow Leopard was the firs to have this revision so you'll need to grab the updated Xcode.

∴ rvm notes

> Notes for Darwin ( Mac OS X )
>      For Snow Leopard be sure to have Xcode Tools Version 3.2.1 (1613) or later
>      You should download the latest Xcode tools from developer.apple.com.
>        (This is since the dvd install for Snow Leopard contained bugs).
>
> If you intend on installing MacRuby you must install LLVM first.
>      If you intend on installing JRuby you must install the JDK.
>      If you intend on installing IronRuby you must install Mono
>        (version 2.6 or greater is recommended).
>
> To use an RVM installed Ruby as default instead of the system ruby:
>      rvm install 1.8.7 # installs patch 352: closest supported version
>      rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.8.7 ; rvm gemset import system
>      migrate your gems
>      rvm --default 1.8.7
>
> NOTE:
>   As of 1.8.0 RVM once again loads .rvmrc files, by default, after asking your
>    permission to trust it of course.  If you do not wish to be enabled, simply set:
>        export rvm_project_rvmrc=0
>    Within either your /etc/rvmrc or $HOME/.rvmrc file. This will turn off the
>    cd/pushd hooks when sourcing the rvm() function into your shell.
>
> Example: echo 'export rvm_project_rvmrc=0' >> $HOME/.rvmrc;
>     (Then close the current shell and open a new one.)

As of this writing the current RVM is 1.8.3, the required Xcode is minimally 3.2.1, and you can use either the readline in Homebrew, RVM's 'rvm pkg install readline' or Lion's built-in readline (though there have been significant reports of that failing).

You would pass that info in as shown on the site.