# RVM does not install ruby 1.9.2 on Snow Leopard error with make and gcc error

Tags: ruby, osx-snow-leopard

I checked out this thread:

[RVM Does Not Install Ruby 1.9.2 on Snow Leopard: 'Error running 'make '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671074/rvm-does-not-install-ruby-1-9-2-on-snow-leopard-error-running-make)

But I am getting different errors in my log when I attempt to install ruby 1.9.2.

The message is:

```
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /Users/myusername/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/make.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

When I open up my log, I see:

```
[2011-08-16 15:45:55] make
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
gcc -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -W$
```

I have tried using

```
rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-readline-dir=/usr/local
```

after following instructions from the previously mentioned post (compiling and installing readline)

Comment: Please add the specific errors you're getting to the question.

Comment: Added it to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/07/08/installing-ruby-1-9-2-with-rvm-on-snow-leopard/

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p136 --with-readline-dir=/opt/local
```