# Can't compile ruby 1.9.3 with rvm on Snow Leopard

Tags: rvm

when I run

```
rvm -install 1.9.3
```

I get an make error. This is the last few lines of the log.

```
compiling readline.c
readline.c: In function    sername_completion_proc_call
readline.c:1499: error:    sername_completion_function   undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:1499: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:1499: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[2]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/readline/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Any suggestions? I know I've got another version of ruby installed. Is that causing it, and if so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with readline. Apparently a lot of people have this issue, and the solution is to just compile readline yourself. Found the answer here: [Error installing ruby 1.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962550/error-installing-ruby-1-9-3)

Comment: rvm has a task to install different packages: `rvm pkg install readline`