# installing ruby 1.9.3 in michael hartl's ruby on rails tutorial

Tags: railstutorial.org, ruby-1.9.3, installation

I'm working on Michael Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec-development_tools.

I installed Git, updated my OS to 10.8.2 and downloaded XCode 4.5.2.

when I type in

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

this long thing comes up...

```
Ruby (and needed base gems) for your selection will be installed shortly.
Before it happens, please read and execute the instructions below.
Please use a separate terminal to execute any additional commands.

  Notes for Mac OS X 10.8.2, Xcode 4.5.2.

For JRuby:  Install the JDK. See http://developer.apple.com/java/download/  # Current Java version "1.6.0_26"
For IronRuby: Install Mono >= 2.6
For Ruby 1.9.3: Install libksba # If using Homebrew, 'brew install libksba'
For Opal: Install Nodejs with NPM. See http://nodejs.org/download/

To use an RVM installed Ruby as default, instead of the system ruby:

    rvm install 1.8.7 # installs patch 357: closest supported version
    rvm system ; rvm gemset export system.gems ; rvm 1.8.7 ; rvm gemset import system.gems # migrate your gems
    rvm alias create default 1.8.7

And reopen your terminal windows.

Xcode and gcc:

Right now Ruby requires gcc to compile, but Xcode 4.2 and later no longer ship with gcc. Instead they ship with llvm-gcc (to which gcc is a symlink) and clang, neither of which are supported for building Ruby. Xcode 4.1 was the last version to ship gcc, which was /usr/bin/gcc-4.2.

Xcode 4.1 and earlier:
- Ruby will build fine.

Xcode 4.2 and later (including Command Line Tools for Xcode):
- If you have gcc-4.2 (and friends) from an earlier Xcode version, Ruby will build fine.
- If you don't have gcc-4.2, you have two options to get it:
 * Install apple-gcc42 from Homebrew
 * Install osx-gcc-installer

  Homebrew:

  If you are using Homebrew, you can install the apple-gcc42 and required libraries from homebrew/dupes:

      brew update
      brew tap homebrew/dupes
      brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
      rvm pkg install openssl

  Xcode 4.2+ install or/and Command Line Tools for Xcode is required to provide make and other tools.

  osx-gcc-installer:

  If you don't use Homebrew, you can download and install osx-gcc-installer: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer.

  Warning: Installing osx-gcc-installer on top of a recent Xcode is known to cause problems, so you must uninstall Xcode before installing osx-gcc-installer. Afterwards you may install Xcode 4.2+ or Command Line Tools for Xcode if you desire.

  ** NOTE: Currently, Node.js is having issues building with osx-gcc-installer. The only fix is to install Xcode over osx-gcc-installer.

Press 'q' to continue.
~
(END)
```

Originally I had to get homebrew and

```
brew install libksba
```

but I did that already and it works.  That leads to "Xcode and gcc:" and everything below it.

So, I have homebrew, and the following three commands work:

```
  brew update
  brew tap homebrew/dupes
  brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
```

But when I try

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

this is what happens

```
Fetching openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/archives
Extracting openssl to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c
Configuring openssl in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Compiling openssl in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Error running 'make', please read /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/openssl/make.log

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Updating openssl certificates
Error running 'update_openssl_certs', please read /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/openssl.certs.log
```

And this is what happens when I try what it says...

```
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ rvm reinstall all --force
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$
```

some other information...

I don't see a .rvm folder under adamzerner, so I can't read what it tells me to (not that I would understand what I'd be reading anyway).

It seems that I have 1.8.7 installed:

```
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

So... to summarize... when I try to run

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

I get the gcc/Xcode problem.  To fix that it says to download apple-gcc42 from Homebrew.  When I do that, I get a problem after doing

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

The problem being that I need to reinstall all rubies.  When I do that:

```
rvm reinstall all --force
```

it seems that nothing happens.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me with this problem!

EDIT: I forgot to say this before.  For the "long thing" up above, when I press q to continue, this is what happens...

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p327.tar.bz2 - #configure
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #download
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extract
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #validate
Libraries missing for ruby-1.9.3-p327: env. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries
Mounting remote ruby failed, trying to compile.
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4
Configuring yaml in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make', please read /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/yaml/make.log
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extracted to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #configuring
Error running './configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

EDIT: What happens when I follow the github link OliverAtkinson posted

```
Last login: Wed Dec 26 15:55:12 on ttys000
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ brew update
Updated Homebrew from 751a0d6e to c67c126c.
==> New Formulae
ume
==> Updated Formulae
akka        global      markdown    ruby        slrn
basex       gnuplot     mu      ruby-build  ttytter
casperjs    gradle      qt      shiboken    vice
cassandra   groonga     qt5     shocco      wine
discount    jenkins     rakudo-star signing-party   xvid
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
Error: Already tapped!
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
Error: autoconf-2.69 already installed
Error: automake-1.12.6 already installed
Error: apple-gcc42-4.2.1-5666.3 already installed
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ brew remove autoconf automake apple-gcc42
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69...
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.12.6...
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3...
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file bin/autoreconf.in
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69
==> make install
/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69: 69 files, 2.0M, built in 13 seconds
==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/automake/automake-1.12.6.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/automake-1.12.6.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.12.6
==> make install
/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.12.6: 130 files, 2.1M, built in 16 seconds
==> Downloading http://r.research.att.com/tools/gcc-42-5666.3-darwin11.pkg
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/apple-gcc42-4.2.1-5666.3.pkg
==> Caveats
NOTE:
This formula provides components that were removed from XCode in the 4.2
release. There is no reason to install this formula if you are using a
version of XCode prior to 4.2.

This formula contains compilers built from Apple's GCC sources, build
5666.3, available from:

  http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/gcc

All compilers have a `-4.2` suffix. A GFortran compiler is also included.
==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3: 104 files, 75M, built in 5 seconds
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ rvm pkg install openssl
Fetching openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/archives
Extracting openssl to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c
Configuring openssl in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Compiling openssl in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/openssl-1.0.1c.
Error running 'make', please read /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/openssl/make.log

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force

Updating openssl certificates
Error running 'update_openssl_certs', please read /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/openssl.certs.log
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --patch falcon --force-autoconf -j 3
Removing /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327...
/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 has already been removed.
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4
Configuring yaml in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make -j3', please read /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/yaml/make.log
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p327, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p327 to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #extracted to /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327
Applying patch /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p327/falcon.diff
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #autoreconf-f
ruby-1.9.3-p327 - #configuring
Error running './configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327 --with-opt-dir=/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
Adam-Zerners-MacBook-Pro:~ adamzerner$
```

Comment: what happens when you `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/gcc` and re run the ruby install?

Comment: Does the solution is [this StackOverflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7962550/567863) work for you?

Comment: @OliverAtkinson is that all in one line? and should i type "usr" or "adamzerner"?

Comment: @Paul Floravanti I'm not sure.  I don't understand what's going on there enough, and I'm following a somewhat rigid rails tutorial and I'm not sure if doing something it says there will negate/interfere with anything I've done or will be doing in the tutorial.

Comment: @AdamZerner copy and paste exactly what I put - and yes its /usr/

Comment: @OliverAtkinson when I copy and paste what you put and then re run the ruby install, the same "long thing" comes up

Comment: take a look here, maybe it can help: https://gist.github.com/3831948

Comment: @OliverAtkinson I'm not sure that it solved my problem.  It doesn't seem that ruby 1.9.3 was downloaded for him or for me.  I posted what happened as an edit to my original question.

Comment: @AdamZerner what is the output in `/Users/adamzerner/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p327/configure.log` if you want bring it to discussion so we don't block up this question from other answers

Comment: @OliverAtkinson I'm new to this site.  What do you mean by "bring it to discussion"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully downloaded Ruby 1.9.3 now!

I think the problem was that I hadn't downloaded Command Line Tools from XCode.  See http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion

note that for `whoami`, it's using the backtick key, which is right above the tab key.  It is NOT using quotes.

After I downloaded Command Line Tools, I then typed in `rvm install 1.9.3`.  I got the same "long thing" as before, but at that point I had everything I needed, so I just pressed q to continue, and ruby 1.9.3 was successfully installed!

note: although it was successfully installed, when I typed `ruby -v`, it still said it was 1.8.7 even though it wasn't.  However, after closing and reopening the terminal, it then said that the version was indeed 1.9.3.

Comment: Great that you were able to solve your own problem.  Please mark your answer as "accepted" for everyone's reference.